# Слишком много корзин на одном не системном диске в Windows 7

Tags: windows

Сейчас установлена Windows 7 х64, имеются один SSD и два HDD. На системном SSD одна корзина, а на всех разделах HDD очень много развелось корзин. Система переустанавливалась много раз, форматировался только SSD. Нужно ли столько корзин на каждом диске?
Файл desktop.ini есть только в одной папке, а остальные папки пустые.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это остались корзины старых пользователей прошлых установленных систем. Можно смело из-под livecd грохать всю $RECYCLE.BIN - текущая система пересоздаст всё что нужно автоматически.

Comment: Все получилось даже из под винды в Total Commander! Я давно это хотел сделать но побаивался.  А вот если грохнуть из под  livecd папку  System Volume Information не на системном диске конечно, то она тоже перезапишется?

Comment: Да. Я так постоянно делаю, когда ставлю на один комп сначала винду, а потом линукс. В этом сценарии гарантированно убивается диск `D:\`, а потом пересоздаётся заново. Винда даже не прочухивает, что что-то поменялось.